# date_select and html_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I wan't to override the css class from `date_select`.  I have managed to drop the default css classes (year, month, day) but I can't apply the new css_classes.  Here is the code;

```
f.date_select(:date, options: { with_css_classes: true }, html_options: { class: "form-control" } )
```

Comment: Try making html_options: html:

Comment: Use this syntax instead: `f.date_select(:date, { with_css_classes: true }, { class: "form-control" } )`

Comment: changing `html_options:` to `html:` yields same results

Comment: `f.date_select(:date, { with_css_classes: true }, { class: "form-control" } )` is a step backwards - the default css classes are no longer omitted.

Comment: Given, that `options:{}` is required to invoked the options inside the hash, I believe that `html_options: {}` is the correct syntax, but the data_select expects some other parameter name...one that is not documented correctly.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks like Bootstrap? If you want to override the class everywhere in the app, not just one place, you could always extend the CSS in your assets/stylesheets directory.

Comment: I am trying to follow through the Rails source to see what is going on...html_options does seem to be the right name for the parameter. `@html_options` get set in `DateTimeSelector.new` but then I loose track of it.  I think that `build_selects_from_types` is the method that outputs the HTML, and I don't see it referencing `@html_options`.  Anyone with better Ruby chops see this differently?

Comment: You get this figured out?

Comment: There was a bug in Rails. Looks like it will be available in the next release. see: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14468

Answer (score 1):

I think the docs are weird about this.  I had best results without using `with_css_classes: true`.  Just be sure to do the right curly placements. Like so:

```
f.date_select :date, {}, {:class => "form-control"}
```